# How do I configure apache2 to serve static assets from server root subdirectory?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, static-content

Front end developer here - I just inherited a server (Mac Pro) to host my prototypes within our network.  There's already an apache server set up on it, but I don't know much about it's config.  This is a shared server, so while the server root is set up at `/Users/Shared`, I only have permissions to place my prototypes at

`/Shared/mydiv/mydept/prototypes`

I build my site with webpack and it places static assets in a `dist` directory.  The server configuration is working; users can browse to `sharedserver.url.com/mydiv/mydept/prototypes` and the index.html is served correctly.

The problem is that index.html references `scripts.js`, also located within the `dist` directory, but the web server is looking for them in the server root at sharedserver.url.com, which obviously returns a 404.

I'm referencing scripts in index.html like this:

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Likewise, I need to reference some fonts located in `dist/fonts`.

```
sharedserver.url.com/   <-- APACHE TRYING TO ACCESS STATIC ASSETS HERE
|_mydiv/
   |_ mydept/
      |_ prototypes/
         |_ _ dist/
                |_ index.html
                |_ scripts.js  <-- REALLY WISH APACHE LOOK FOR STATIC ASSETS HERE 
                | _ _fonts/
                       |_.eof,.ttf,etc.
```

I've read a little about using vhosts but the module is not already loaded in httpd.conf (commented out) and I don't want to cause a conflict with existing configuration, which I don't yet fully have my head around.  I've also read about .htaccess files but AllowOverride is set to None in httpd.conf - I could change it and then start learning about .htaccess but I wonder if there's another way as I am inexperienced setting up this sort of thing.

Are there any other (easyish) ways to get apache to look for my static assets in my directory?

Comment: A frontend developer venturing into server configutation? Kudos to you, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your document root is set like this

```
DocumentRoot "/sharedserver.url.com"
```

and you want it like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/sharedserver.url.com/mydiv/mydept/prototypes/dist"
```

and the directory path must be the same as document root

```
<Directory "/sharedserver.url.com/mydiv/mydept/prototypes/dist">
```

if you do it like this and used your domain url you will be taken to index.html and your script will be shown correctly

I hope this would fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case it was caused by the value of the `base` tag inside the head section of the index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

This set the base URL for relative URLs to the server root. I could solve the problem by removing/altering the `base` tag.

I hope this helps.